# What is the possible reason to get this output?

Tags: java, methods, constructor

This was a question I found in some web site.The code goes like this.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new B();
  }
}

class A {
  int i = 7;

  public A() {
   setI(20);
   System.out.println("i from A is " + i);
  }

  public void setI(int i) {
    this.i = 2 * i;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public B() {
    // System.out.println("i from B is " + i);
  }

  public void setI(int i) {
    this.i = 3 * i;
  }
}
```

I would like to know why the output of this is i from A is 60 and not 40. Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Why would you expect it to be 40? It's hard to correct your train of thought when you don't express it.

Comment: If you expect it to be 40, then you completely ignore the idea of polymorphism. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple polymorphism.

You are creating a B object, so when the A constructor is invoking setI(), it is calling the "B version" (which leads to 3*20 = 60).

In other words: when you call a method on a object in Java, the JVM will check at **runtime** of which **concrete** class that object is; and invoke the method it finds on **that** class. Thus: setI() is called exactly once, in its "B" version.

You can easily figure that when you put different print line statements into the two setters.

Comment: So the method setI() in A is never called.Is it?

Comment: Got it. Thanks!! =)